# populate two seperate structs from ini file in c

Tags: c

I need to populate two separate structs from values in a .ini in c. The .ini file looks like

```
[NAMES]
john,01,email address
tom,02,email address
jane,03,email address
[SERVER]
server1,test.servername.com
server2,testother.server.com
```

the typedef structs that is then need to populate will be, populate the first form NAMES and then the second from SERVER

The structs will be

```
typedef struct
{
char name;
int id;
char email;
} namesBuffer;

typedef struct
{
char server1;
char server2
} serverBuffer;
```

I need to code this in c, does anyone have any suggestions/examples on how to do this. Do I need to search the .ini file for the different section names[] and copy each line into the appropriate struct.

Comment: `char` can hold only one character.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick search and I found a simple INI parser for C:
https://github.com/benhoyt/inih

My suggestion for the part with the splits at the commas would be using `strtok`, example from http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
...
const char string[] = "jane,03,email address";
const char delimiters[] = ",";
char *cp;

cp = strdup(string);                   /* Make writable copy.  */
str_name = strtok(cp, delimiters);      // -> "jane"
str_nr   = strtok(NULL, delimiters);    // -> "03"
str_mail = strtok(NULL, delimiters);    // -> "email address"
```

Of course you have to define the three strings first.
I don't know if it is a convention, but as I remember ini-Files should look something like this:

```
[section]
variable1=a
variable2=b
```

But of course you can load everything you want and parse it. For the section name just set the delimiter to `"[]"` to get the name of the section.